# How to make site redirect to same page before refreshing - PHP

Tags: php, refresh, redirect

I am trying to make the user redirect back to the `#contact page` before refreshing. But when clicking send message the site goes back to the first page and I have to scroll all the way down to `#contact page` and then 5 seconds later it refreshes back to the first page (which is good). My code is below:

**PHP**

```
<?php




if($_POST['submit']){




   if(!$_POST['name']){
      $error= "<br/>-Please enter your name" ;

}

     if(!$_POST['email']){
      $error.= "<br/>-Please enter your email" ;

   }

    if (trim($_POST['message']) == "")
{
   $error.= "<br/>-Please enter message";
}

   if(!$_POST['contact']!=$match){
      $error.= "<br/>-Please enter your contact number" ;

   }


    if ($error){
      $result= "Whoops, error: $error"; 

    }


   else{
       mail('mahdi.mashrafi@yahoo.com', "Contact message", "Name: ".$_POST['name']." Email: ".$_POST['email']."
        Email: ".$_POST['name']."
        Message : ".$_POST['message']."
        Contact :".$_POST['contact'] );
     //  header("location:index.php#contact");  
       header( "refresh:5; url = index.php#contact" ); //wait for 5 seconds before redirecting  

        {
        $result= "Thankyou, Ill be in touch shortly";

        }






    }


}


?>
```

I have commented out one header or else the `$result` wont show in the contact form. How can I make it that when user sends message instead of going back to first page it redirects back to the `#contact` page still displaying the `$result` and later refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you would like to go to #contact just after submitting and then five second later the page will be refreshed and go to #contact ?

In that case, you might want to add #contact in your form action :

```
<form action="mypage.php#contact">
...
</form>
```